# How to create Teams as Private team using Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-teams

When we see from Teams UI while we create new Teams, we can choose the option of public and private.

Can I Create Teams as a Private team using Graph API? If so, can anyone help me to find the related document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Karen You cannot set the visibility directly on the team. Instead, you could set [visibility of the group to Private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-create-group-and-team) and create the team upon that group.

Comment: If we have Teams using create-team PowerShell, is this teams will be a public by default?

Comment: $group = New-Team -MailNickname "TestTeam" -displayname "Test Teams" -Visibility "private"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/new-team?view=teams-ps This visibility option seems available?

Answer (score 0):

Here, for the API:
"v1.0/groups/{ID}" -Body '{"visibility": "Private"}' -Method PATCH